# What is the format of `camel.sink.endpoint.connectionFactory` (for Camel Bigquery Kafka Sink Connector)?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-camel

I am trying to use the Camel Google Bigquery Kafka Sink Connector in a Strimzi Kubernetes deployment.

Referring to this [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/reference/connectors/camel-google-bigquery-kafka-sink-connector.html) on Camel's website, I cannot find any reference to the format required for the "connectionFactory".

Can somebody give me an example of the `camel.sink.endpoint.connectionFactory`? Thanks!